# DB2 SQL Find the Id of Suppliers, who supply specific color

Tags: sql, db2

Find the id of the suppliers, who supply color red or blue. And is this possible to do it without using the join statement.

```
num     suppliers    color 
------  ------- --------
 1       Sam     yellow
 2       Ana     black 
 3       Eva     red 
 4       Tom     blue
 5       Simon   blue
 6       Ema     green

  id   num
 ---- ------
  01   1
  02   2
  03   3  
  04   4
  05   5
  05   4
```

And the result should be something like this:

```
  id   suppliers  color
 ----- ------ -------
  03    Eva    red
  04    Tom    blue
  05    Simon  blue
  05    Tom    blue
```

My solution is this, but is still not giving me the result it should be.
Can someone, please help me?

```
 select id, suppliers, color
 from suppliers, parts 
 where color = 'blue' or color = 'red';
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `JOIN`?  (And to be precise, `JOIN` is an operator, not a statement.)

Comment: You're doing a join already, an implicit, comma separated one. Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Because this is my assignment requirement. And I should use something else.

Comment: Who gave you that assignment - your teacher or your manager?!?

Comment: @jarlh My teacher

Comment: Why did you tag DB2 and MySQL? Which one is it?

Comment: I'd like to hear your teacher's explanation of why to avoid a join, because a join is what you use here!

Comment: @TheImpaler It's DB2... was a suggestion from stackoverflow for my post to be more visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a join already - an implicit, comma separated one.

Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. **Easier to write (without errors)**, easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

```
select p.id, s.suppliers, s.color
from suppliers s
JOIN parts p ON s.num = p.num
where s.color IN ('blue', 'red')
```

Also use table aliases (`s`, `p`), and qualify the columns, e.g. `s.num`.

JOIN-free version:

```
select *
from
(
    select p.id,
           (select s.suppliers from suppliers s where s.num = p.num) suppliers,
           (select s.color from suppliers s where s.num = p.num) color
    from parts p
) dt
where color in ('blue', 'red');
```

Comment: Argh.  Please, don't teach the student to use single-letter aliases.  These table names aren't really even long enough for it to matter.